# magento 2 list not showing in Stores > Settings > All Stores

Tags: multistore, store-view, magento2.3.5-p1

i'm trying to setup a new magento site in 2.3.5p1 with multiple store views. after creating all the store views, i added all products. Now when i visit the stores list in Stores > Settings > All stores, the list has gone missing, although the number of records says 10. Below is the image for ref. Please advise how to resolve.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run indexer command again.